# Interaction upon deletion between Thunderbird and Yahoo webmail

Tags: sync, thunderbird, webmail, yahoo-mail

I'd like to be able to delete some messages from my Inbox in Thunderbird without having those messages deleted from my Inbox on the Yahoo server.

How do I reach this result ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the POP3 protocol instead of the IMAP protocol.

IMAP essentially keeps every device in sync with the server, such that every device acts like a mirror.
POP3 will go online and download the messages from the server, and then, *at your discretion* you can make your client automatically delete them from the server, which it sounds like you don't want.

Just be careful with POP3. You can end up with either of the following scenarios:

1. Email messages will never get deleted from the server at all
2. You enable the feature to make your email client delete messages as they are downloaded, then you end up with a different version of your email account on every device, such that if you're looking for a message you have to remember which device you were working on when you checked your email.

I personally recommend keeping IMAP set up and simply designating an archive folder to act in place of a trash. If you have another reason why you would want to delete a local copy, please leave a comment on this answer.